# Can an HDMI input marked "ARC" be used for ordinary video?

Tags: video, hdmi

If a television has one of its HDMI inputs marked "ARC" can I use that input for regular video input?

Comment: All knowing Google, purveyor of all knowledge, decrees: Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I have one on my TV and it works fine with normal HDMI input.

ARC stands for Audio Return Channel. It allows digital audio to be sent back down the HDMI cable in the reverse direction to the video signal. Using it is optional so sending HDMI video and audio signals in the forward direction should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is simply marked to know which input is compatible for connecting to an amplifier.